# Embeddings of reductive groups over algebraically closed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $K/k$ be an extension of fields, not necessarily algebraic; let $G$ and $H$ be split, reductive groups over $K$; and let $f : H \to G$ be an embedding of groups.

Do there exist split, reductive groups $G'$ and $H'$ over $k$, an embedding $f' : H' \to G'$ of groups, and isomorphisms $G'_K \cong G$ and $H'_K \cong H$ such that $f'_K$ is identified to $f$?

If it helps, $k$ and $K$ can both be assumed algebraically closed.  (I would not be surprised if this assumption is necessary, but I would also not be surprised if just being split is enough.)

(I could ask this question with fixed $k$-groups $H'$ and $G'$ at the beginning, consider a morphism $f : H'_K \to G'_K$, and then ask for $f'$, but in that case the answer is ‘no’; for example, take $H' = \operatorname{GL}_1$ and $G' = \operatorname{SL}_2$, and let $f$ be any embedding of $H'_K$ as a maximal split torus in $G'_K$ that is not defined over $k$.  If I did not require that $G$ and $H$ be split over $K$, then the answer would be ‘no’ just because one or both of them might not admit a $k$-form.)

This seems like it's in the spirit of [Borel and Tits - Homomorphismes “abstraits” …](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970833), but I couldn't find it there or deduce it from the results of that paper.

Comment: The following might work.

 Choose a finitely generated $k$-subalgebra $R\subset K$, choose split reductive group schemes $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ over $S:=\mathrm{Spec} $ $R$, and choose  a closed immersion $\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{G}$ which agrees with $f:H\to G$ after basechange along $\mathrm{Spec} K\to S$.  

Since $k$ is algebraically closed, there is a point $s$ in $S(k)$. Put $H' = \mathcal{H}_s$ and $G':= \mathcal{G}_s$.  My guess is that if $s$ is chosen general enough, then $H'_K = H$ and $G'_K = G$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar, why does a closed immersion $\mathcal H \to \mathcal G$ as in your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431670/embeddings-of-reductive-groups-over-algebraically-closed-fields#comment1111198_431670) exist?  (It may be standard stuff, but, as soon as I get away from groups over fields, I feel lost.)

Comment: @anon, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1111205), I suspect that a torus mapping into a base-changed torus is not enough, and that we need also to map a Borel containing that torus into a base-changed Borel, for example to speak compatibly of a base for the roots.  (But this is just a suspicion.)  But, even with this, I do not see how Steinberg's result does the job.  It *does* seem to make it plausible that we can reduce to the case where $H'$ is $\operatorname{SL}_2$ or $\operatorname{PGL}_2$, but beyond that I cannot see how to proceed.

Comment: @anon, the Sopkina results [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431670/embeddings-of-reductive-groups-over-algebraically-closed-fields#comment1111318_431670) also seem to be about groups containing, or at least normalised by, a maximal torus.  But not every reductive subgroup is.  This arises in [Stewart - The reductive subgroups of $\mathsf F_4$](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0065-9266-2012-00668-X).  If I've misunderstood, maybe you could give a reference to a specific result in the paper?

Comment: @anon, re [1](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1111302), I do not understand how to get $\Delta'$ from $H$ (the $K$-group).  If $H$ contained, or even was normalised by, the maximal torus that you are denoting $T_K$, then it should be fine— though even then I'm sceptical of getting a base unless $H$ contains a Borel in a suitable $B_K$, but that's easily arranged—but, as [above](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1111328), not every reductive subgroup does. (The Steinberg result seems only to construct, not to exhaust.) If I'm missing the point, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @anon, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431670/embeddings-of-reductive-groups-over-algebraically-closed-fields#comment1111349_431670), I think that I have read your comments carefully.  I am reasonably familiar with the Steinberg paper, and cannot access the Sopkina paper so am going from its title.  I have outlined where my difficulties are; but it is easy to believe that I have misunderstood your argument, and I'd be grateful if you could help me correct my misunderstanding.

Comment: This exists by "spreading out" of closed immersions. First choose $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{G}$.  Now use that there is a closed immersion $\mathcal{H}_{L}\to \mathcal{G}_L$ for some finitely generated extension $L$ of $K(S)$ (contained in $K$).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431670/embeddings-of-reductive-groups-over-algebraically-closed-fields#comment1111486_431670)!  Are both of those really supposed to be $K$, or is it, say, $k(S)$?  Is $S$ a transcendence basis for $K/k$?  Also, although I know it's a very elementary question, while I have seen the term "spreading out" before, I have never understood its precise definition.  (As I say, I only really think about algebraic groups over fields.)  Do you know anywhere accessible to read the definition?  (It's hard to Google!)

Comment: I denote the function field of an integral scheme $S$ by $K(S)$. The scheme $S$ is the affine scheme defined by the ring $R$. The ring $R$ is obtained by adjoining to $k$ all the "data" necessary to write down $\mathcal{G}$, $\mathcal{H}$, and so on. Think of it this way: Writing down ${G}$ over $K$ requires only finitely many data (polynomials with finitely many coefficients), so once you choose this data to define $G$ you get an algebraic group over some subring $R\subset K$ with $R$ finitely generated over $k$ (i.e. $R =k[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ for some well-chosen $a_i$ in $K$).

Comment: I would recommend Bjorn Poonen's book on rational points for "spreading out". The idea is very simple. Consider, for example, the polynomial $f(x,y) = y^2 - x^3+10$. This defines an affine scheme $X$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. This scheme is smooth over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e.,  $X_{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+10)$. In particular, by spreading out of smoothness, it is smooth over a dense open of $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$. (What this dense open is precisely can be computed in this case. But in general, spreading out only gives you "some dense open".)

Comment: Another example of spreading out: Consider the morphism $x\mapsto 2x$ from the affine line to itself. This is an honest isomorphism of schemes over $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, by spreading out of isomorphisms, it spreads out to an isomorphism over some dense open of $\mathrm{Spec}$ $\mathbb{Z}$. (In this case, the dense open is $\mathrm{Spec} $ $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.)

Comment: In the above examples, the base scheme is $S:=\mathrm{Spec}$ $\mathbb{Z}$. You have an object $X$ over $S$ satisfying some property over $\mathbb{Q}$ (e.g., smoothness, flatness, normality) and "spreading out" just guarantees that there is a dense open of $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ over which this property persists. You can do this whenever the base scheme $S$ is an integral scheme. (sometimes you need noetherianity depending on what you desire.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In positive characteristic the answer to the question is negative. The reason for that is that there is exists a semisimple groups $H'/k$ admitting a family of finite dimensional representations $\rho_t:H'\to GL(n,k)$, $t\in\mathbb A^1$, whose members are pairwise non-isomorphic. This family then defines a representation $\rho:H_K\to GL(n,K)$ with $K=\overline{k(t)}$ which is certainly not defined over $k$.

To construct such a family, I would look for two simple $H'$-modules $U$ and $W$ with $\dim\mathrm{Ext}^1(U,W)\ge2$. (Maybe some expert can help out with an example.) Then let $c_0$ and $c_1$ be two cocycles which stay linearly independent in $\mathrm{Ext}^1(U,W)$ and let $c_t:=(1-t)c_0+tc_1$. Then $c_t$ defines a representation on $V=U\oplus W$ depending on $t$ such that no two are isomorphic.

Comment: There are many examples, but here is one: take $G$ simple of type $D_n$ with $n \geq 4$ even, over an algebraically closed field of characteristic two. In this case the adjoint module for $G$ has a unique non-trivial composition factor $U$, and $\dim Ext_G^1(U,k) = 2$. By the way, for $G = SL_2$ we have $\dim Ext_G^1(U,W) \leq 1$ for all simple $G$-modules $U$ and $W$.

Comment: My interest was primarily (har har) in positive characteristic.  (This sort of counterexample definitionally doesn't work, and it seems reasonable that the result itself has a chance of being true, for a linearly reductive group, so for all reductive groups in characteristic $0$.)  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it's just occurred to me--are these obviously faithful representations? For an adjoint group I know they can't have a smooth kernel, but could there be an infinitesimal kernel? If so, I guess we just use the isogeny theorem to replace by a suitable quotient.

Comment: Good point. I think one can argue as follows: It follows from Chevalley's isogeny theorem that finite normal subgroup schemes form a discrete set. Therefore, all representations $\rho_t$ have the same kernel $E$ with possibly finitely many exceptions. Now replace $H$ by $H/E$ und you have embeddings.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$I believe it is straightforward that, if one can realise every $\SL_2$-embedding over $k$, then one can realise every (connected) reductive-group embedding over $k$. @MikkoKorhonen's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1113202) shows that the failure for $\SL_2$ can't be for the same reason as in this answer … but doesn't it also outline a simpler counterexample? Since there is a representation $V$ of $\SL_{2, k}$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(V_K, V_K) = K$, can't we choose an extension of $V_K$ by $V_K$ coming from an element of $K \setminus k$?